# how to install Imagic in WAMP server?

Tags: apache, wampserver, imagick, php-7.4

I am getting error **php_imagick.dll is not working. %1 is not a valid W32 application**.

I am using WAMP Server  **Apaches 2.4.4.6 and PHP 7.4.9**. my OS is windows 10 64bit. i think i download  php_imagick-3.6.0rc2-7.3-nts-vc15-x64.zip file.

I have installed all DDL file in **PHP7.4.9/ext/** and apply all process for install **Imagic** but still i am getting error

i have add extension in **php.ini** file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsH9Y.png)

**Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_imagick' (tried: d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.4.9/ext/php_imagick (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.), d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.4.9/ext/php_php_imagick.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0**

i tried to find required file and package form

https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.6.0rc2/ also checked
https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=6359

but nothing helpful for me. that Module is not loading..

please help me....

Comment: I am also facing same problem.

Comment: Which of those zips did you download

Comment: You need this one for WAMPServer `php_imagick-3.6.0rc2-7.4-ts-vc15-x86.zip` The Thread Safe version for WAMPServer 32 bit

Comment: or `php_imagick-3.6.0rc2-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip` for a 64bit WAMPServer

Comment: my system is 64 bit so i thnk i used  php_imagick-3.6.0rc2-7.3-nts-vc15-x64.zip

Comment: i think i also tried that version.

Comment: Check, the NTS (Non Thread safe) version will not run on WAMPServers config

Answer (score 0):

1. check that the dll is not blocked: [image]
2. try downloading the imagick threadsafe for [here](http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/), version made for your PHP version
3. also install it from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) on top of it all